# Permisos adecuados para Apache y FTP en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, permisos

He alquilado un VPS para alojar mi/mis sitios WEB y en la configuración del servidor no estoy especializado. Tengo hecha toda la configuración pero el tema de los permisos me falla. Necesito permisos que me permitan funcionar con el FTP y por otro lado que el usuario de apache `www-data` tenga control también de la carpeta.

Tengo un usuario creado para interactuar con el FTP y lo he metido en el grupo de `www-data`, que es el grupo de apache. La carpeta `/var/www` la tiene de propietario `www-data` y el contenido de `/var/www/html` lo tiene mi usario de FTP, que pertenece al grupo `www-data`.

La cuestión es que estoy obteniendo el error:

```
Warning: copy(/var/www/html/resources/"...."): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/cfg/funciones.php on line xx
```

El problema es que no consigo dar unos permisos que me valgan tanto para que el FTP funcione bien, como para que el apache también funcione sin problemas de permisos.

Me gustaría saber si sabéis como arreglarlo o alguna guía que explique esto bien en detalle.

Un saludo.

Edit: os dejo el resultado de ls -la de las carpetas /var/www y /var/www/html
Ahora mismo está funcionando la subida y el apache correctamente, pero porque tengo puestos todos los permisos al en la carpeta (chmod 777). Me gustaría saber cual es la config adecuada para que funcione tanto el ftp como para que el apache tenga permisos.

[image: ls -la]

Comment: Que servidor FTP estas utilizando? VSFPTD? ProFTP? Es importante que compartas información de eso.

Comment: Cierto, disculpa. Uso vsftpd. Y el cliente es FileZilla.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega los resultados de los comandos `ls -l /var/www` y `ls -l /var/www/html`, y detalla si al momento **VSFTP** te esta funcionando correctamente(conecta, sube, y descarga archivos).

Comment: Añadido, espero que sirva con eso.

Comment: ¿Has manejado consola ssh? ¿Qué sistema operativo tiene tu vps? De entrada te recomendaría que descargaras putty o bitvise (son clientes ssh) y que te autenticaras con los parámetros que te dió tu proveedor.

Comment: @PAGANA Ubuntu 16.04, y claro que he manejado la consola SSH. Es como he configurado todo el servidor, a través de Putty.

Comment: ¿Intentaste con sudo usermod -aG www-data tu-nombre-de-usuario, luego sudo chown tu-nombre-de-usuario:www-data -R /var/www/html? Sino te explico cómo lo configuré.

Comment: Reinstalé el VPS y he configurado webmin, creo que tengo los permisos correctamente configurados ahora ya que con la interfaz de webmin es más fácil. De momento todo funcionando!